# Can someone please explain to me this hand below:

Tags: tournament

I here again with another Poker question.
The percentage of both player is showing 0% and the commentator is addressing that both player have equally the same hand value with whats shown on the bard no players win ..I don't get it! I thought a straight is a stronger hand than two pair which is what the other player have.I am super confused :( 
I am new a Poker and I would really appreciate if someone can explain this to me.
 Many Thanks.[image: As you see in the picture Meijer has a straight and Czuczor tow pairs, no one has a flush though]

Answer (score 2):

Split pot 
Both have the same flush

Comment: Thank you for answering my query I really appreciate it. So because there is a Flash Meijer hand(Q,J) that made the straight cancels out ? what if the other player would've have 2,3 hearts against the (Q,J) ? split pot again ? regardless what hands they had(nos  spade) would still be split pot? I am sorry if I am asking too much I really like Poker and I want to learn to play Properly .

Comment: Yes, regardless of the hands, if no player has a spade it's a split pot in Texas holdem

Comment: Only with a J(s) to make the Royal flush

Comment: Or a spade larger than the 8 could this pot not be split

Comment: Thank you so much Jill Hemphill for explaining this to me , I now understand.